# I have a problem with Image View Size on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, size

[image]

I try to make Droid Cafe app, and I input this code to my XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/content_main" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView android:id="@+id/textintro" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/intro_text" android:textSize="@dimen/text_heading" android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/choose_dessert" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/textintro" android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular" android:text="@string/choose_a_dessert"/>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/donut" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/choose_dessert" android:contentDescription="@string/donuts" android:onClick="showDonutOrder" android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular" android:src="@drawable/donut_circle"/>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="@dimen/padding_wide" android:layout_below="@id/choose_dessert" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/donut" android:text="@string/donuts" android:layout_toEndOf="@id/donut"/>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/ice_cream" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/donut" android:contentDescription="@string/ice_cream_sandwiches" android:onClick="showIceCreamOrder" android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular" android:src="@drawable/icecream_circle"/>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/donut" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ice_cream" android:padding="@dimen/padding_wide" android:text="@string/ice_cream_sandwiches" android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ice_cream"/>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/froyo" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/ice_cream" android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular" android:contentDescription="@string/froyo" 
android:src="@drawable/froyo_circle" android:onClick="showFroyoOrder"/>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/ice_cream" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/froyo" android:padding="@dimen/padding_wide" android:text="@string/froyo" android:layout_toEndOf="@id/froyo"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But I got a problem with the Size, the Donut and the Ice Scream Sandwich have the same size, but the last one, the FroYo is so different, it's too small.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please attach the `XML` as well

Comment: @AliAhsan: the XML is now added.

Comment: with the formatting this is hard to read... but as i answered below, it will be due to the image size of the source.

Answer (score 0):

Your stored image files probably have different sizes. upload the image again with the same size/dp or set fix dp (like 100dp) for layout_width and layout_height of the imageview.